# MYSQL How to fetch the first row before group by

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

I am trying to fetch products grouped by it's group code, but sorted by it's selling price.

When I run this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.base_model, p.group_code, p.retail_price, p.selling_price, option_name
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id
WHERE (pc.category_id = ?
  AND (p.active = ?)
  AND (pfv1.filter_id = ?)
  AND (pfv1.filter_value_id IN (?))
  AND (p.type = "shop")
  AND (p.group_code = ?)
ORDER BY IF(p.combideal_active = 1, p.combideal_price, p.selling_price) asc
```

I am getting this result:
[image]

When I add a group by and run this query:

```
SELECT p.id, p.base_model, p.group_code, p.retail_price, p.selling_price, option_name
FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN product_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
    LEFT JOIN product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id
WHERE (pc.category_id = ?)
  AND (p.active = ?)
  AND (pfv1.filter_id = ?)
  AND (pfv1.filter_value_id IN (?))
  AND (p.type = "shop")
  AND (p.group_code = ?)
GROUP BY p.group_code
ORDER BY IF(p.combideal_active = 1, p.combideal_price, p.selling_price) asc
```

I am getting this result:
[image: Result 2]

You can see, this is not the cheapest product from the first query. Can anyone help me out to getting the cheapest one as the result?

Comment: What is your version of MySQL? You are using non-standard behaviour as you have selected fields which are neither grouped by, nor aggregated.

Comment: I am using MySQL version 5.7

Comment: What do you expect as output when more than one product has the minimum price (in the same group)?

Comment: Why do you group by `group_code` when the `WHERE` clause only accepts one particular group?

Comment: When more than one product has the minimum price in the same group, it does not matter which product the output is given. I just want to show what the cheapest product is. I used a group_code in the where clause to make it working for one group, But it has to be working for multiple groups at the same time. I Hope you will understand me.

Comment: You are misusing MySQL's [notorious nonstandard extension to GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html). Disable that extension with `SET sql_mode = CONCAT_WS(',',@@sql_mode, 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY')`, then try your query again. You'll need more terms in your GROUP BY clause.

Comment: After doing that, my current sql_node is:
`ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION`
The result of my query is not changed.

Comment: Which more terms should I add to my GROUP BY?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of operations are easy to perform in MySQL 8.x, using window functions. But there is no such thing in MySQL 5.7.

You could however use `group_concat` like this:

```
select p.*
from   product p
inner join (
    select   p.group_code,
             cast(substring_index(group_concat(p.id 
                 order by if(p.combideal_active = 1, p.combideal_price, p.selling_price) 
                 separator ','
             ), ',', 1) as unsigned) id
    from     product p
    left join product_category pc ON pc.product_id = p.id
    left join product_filter_value pfv1 ON p.id = pfv1.product_id
    where /* ...etc... */
    group by p.group_code
) grouped on  p.id = grouped.id;
```

Comment: Yes, tested this code and worked for me! Thanks, you made my day!